# como sacar el valor mayor de varios datos entre los que hay una suma

Tags: oracle

tengo una base de datos de pedidos y un ejercicio que me pide sacar el nombre del cliente que gastó mas dinero

el cliente que gastó más dinero hizo mas de un pedido y los precios de los pedidos y los nombres están en diferentes tablas por lo que no puede hacerse con un simple select max

he logrado hacer esto e intentado de 1 millon de maneras distintas pero ninguna me resulta:

```
select nombre, sum(precio_unitario) as total
from clientes
inner join pedidos on pedidos.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente
inner join detalles_pedido on detalles_pedido.id_pedido=pedidos.id_pedido
group by nombre;
```

esto me muestra una tabla con la cantidad total que gastó cada cliente pero yo solo quiero sacar el nombre del que gastó más, como lo hago?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! una posible solucion (para que aprendas a buscar).. ordena por el total, y quedate con el primer registro (busca rownum ;) )

Comment: de acuerdo al ejercicio se supone que debería poder hacerlo sin rownum eso pero no se me ocurre nada

Comment: entonces. usa esta consulta como subconsulta, y ahora si hace un max sobre la columna total, y luego agregale los datos que faltan...

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/2553194) puedes encontrar varias formas de quedarte solo con el primer elemento que te devuelve una consulta. Hay más opciones aparte de rownum listadas ahí